# Why do I get this output?

Tags: java, recursion

why do i get this output ? I expect the output to be 10,9,8...

But it is 11,12,13....

```
class tester {

    static int i = 0;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        recursive();
        System.out.println("after recursive");
    }

    public static void recursive() {
        while(i++<10) {
            recursive();
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: that's the essence of recursion !

Comment: You really should just step through with a debugger rather than ask SO. It would have easily shown you what's happening.

Comment: The asker has not done the due diligence of debugging through the code first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple logic is as follows:

Since your incremental is a [posfix increment](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html), the original value is evaluated first, before increment.

Logic:

```
while (i++ < 10) { recursive();}
```

1. `i` is initially `0`, so, `0 < 10` (true), increment by 1. Now, call `recursive()`.

This loops (1) until `i = 10`. When `i = 10` is evaluated, the while expression is `false`, so it leaves the loop.

Remember, we have already called `recursive()` 10 times already, so it now needs to print `i`, 10 times, (since the JVM pushed `recursive()` function 10 times in the stack). Each times it pops the function, it goes back to the `System.out.println(i)` statement, knowing that `i` was incremented in each call, hence why you see values:

```
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
after recursive
```

That's basically recursion in a nutshell. :-)

Answer (score 1):

It makes recursive calls until `i=10`. `i` is incremented to 11. Then it stops and you start popping back up the stack, printing `i`. That's why it starts with 11. Remember it is going to check the `while` loop condition on the way back up, which increments `i` again each time. That's why it goes to 12, 13,...

Comment: +1 That's the only answer which seems to really answer the question (in my opinion)

Answer (score 0):

It's because your `i` variable is declared outside of your recursive variable, and you are incrementing and recursing before your display it. Don't forget that `i++ < 10` will get to evaluate `i++`, which will increment the value of `i`, even if the result of `i++ < 10` is `false`.

If you manually write down the sequence of `i++` that's a result of your code's execution, and also write down when the value of `i` is displayed, it should all become clear.

Answer (score 0):

The control only reaches `System.out.println` when the recursive calls have stopped, and by that time the guard of the loop is false, which means `i > 10` after the last comparison (`i == 10` in this last comparison, but it gets post-incremented).

Answer (score 0):

You are printing out the value of `i`. Nowhere in your code there's any statement that could *decrease* the value of `i`. Therefore you shouldn't be expecting to see decreasing values being printed out.

That aside, it is generally a bad idea to have recursion keep state in a global variable (here, `i`) as this tends to make it extremely hard to reason about what's happening in the code.